# how to reuse a third-party libXXX.so in JNI of Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

My application is a system app.So I can compile it using mm,but I can't compile it using NDK-BUILD.
I want to use a method of the third-party libXXX.so,I want to make a new libX.so which provide a interface for java code.The key is My cpp file callback the method of the third-party libXXX.so.
  All the corresponding files are in the same directory.Including Android.mk;a.cpp;liborigin.so;a.h.
android.mk ：

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := liboringa.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS    := eng
#LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE         := libfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES      := /a.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES     := /zinnia.h
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

After MM，an error occur：required target“out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/foo-prebuilt.so”。 stop。
  anyone could help？How to write the makefile..

Comment: Where is the third party xxx.so coming from? is another ndk build file?

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko - `mm` is a function added to your env when you prep to build the system, e.g. calling `source build/envsetup.sh`. It's basically calls `make` for all modules in the current folder.

Comment: the so is from http://zinnia.sourceforge.net/.My operating system is ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
sudo vi /etc/profile 
export ANDROID_JAVA_HOME = (java in android root java)
. /etc/profile
```